# Задача для курсовой Сумма цифр массива Java

Tags: java

Ребята, помогите решить задачу.

Условие задачи: Найти сумму всех цифр целочисленного массива (числа только положительные). Например, если дан массив [12, 104, 81], то сумма всех его цифр будет равна `1 + 2 + 1 + 0 + 4 + 8 + 1 = 17`.

я начала так:

```java
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    private static Object length;
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
        int positives = 0;
        int[ ] array = {12,104,81}
      
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] > 0) {
                sum += array[i];
                array [i] / =10;
                positives++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
        System.out.printf(" Кол-во положительных чисел: " + positives);
    
    }
}
```

Но мой вариант суммирует 12+104+81 , а мне необходимо узнать сумму 1+2+1+0+4+8+1.

Comment: Чем именно помочь?

Comment: Необходимо написать код на java. Буду признательна за помощь :)

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Исправила. Спасибо за поправку)

Comment: Мой вариант кода суммирует 12+104+81, а мне  необходимо вывести в консоль сумму 1 + 2 + 1 + 0 + 4 + 8 + 1 = 17, и только положительные числа, как я поняла из задания.

Comment: вариант для вас: 1) перевести каждое число в строку и сконкатенировать их. 2) разбить строку на символы. 3) пробежаться по массиву и просуммировать отдельные символы (числа)

Comment: получится длинный код. А есть более короткий вариант кода?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский спасибо за подсказку, попробую ваш вариант.

Comment: Какая вам разница длинный код или короткий? Или вы в книге рекордов гиннеса участвуете?))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский разница в том что в таком варианте другие значения кроме как 12,104,81 нужно будет переписывать код меняя все заданные значения. Цикл должен быть рабочий чтобы подставив другие значения в условии { } (условие int[ ]array = new int[3] я переписала на int[ ]array = {12, 104, 81} ) все работало безошибочно не переписывая при этом код. Тоесть надо как-то, каким-то образом, каждое число делить на что-то 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Следует написать функцию, которая определяет сумму цифр в числе (самый простой способ с использованием остатка от деления на 10 для определения каждой цифры), и вызвать её в цикле для положительных элементов массива:

```java
static int digitSum(int n) {
    int sum = 0;
    while (n > 0) {
        sum += n % 10;
        n /= 10;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Вызов в методе `main`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int positives = 0;
    int[ ] array = {12,104,81};
  
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] > 0) {
            sum += digitSum(array[i]);
            positives++;
        }
    }        
    System.out.println(sum);
    System.out.printf(" Кол-во положительных чисел: " + positives);    
}
```

Результат:

```
17
 Кол-во положительных чисел: 3
```

Comment: Прошу прощение мой косяк, была продублирована строка string из-за чего ваш код выдавал 12 ошибок. Все исправила все работает. Спасибо галочку отметила;)